# Type check protocol conformance from extension to a generic

Tags: swift, generics

Given an external type:

```swift
struct Factory<T> {
    public func callAsFunction() -> T {
        registration.resolve(with: ())
    }
}
```

I'm extending it like so:

```swift
// https://github.com/hmlongco/Factory - latest version
import Factory
 
extension Container {
    var logger: Factory<Loggable> { Factory(self) { PrintLogger() } }
}
 
protocol Loggable { }
 
struct PrintLogger: Loggable { }
 
extension Factory {
    func callAsFunction<U>() -> U {
        guard let result = callAsFunction() as? U else {
            preconditionFailure("Found '\(T.self)', but unable to convert it to '\(U.self)'")
        }
        return result
    }
}
 
struct SomeExample {
    func example() {
        // This is valid because PrintLogger implements Loggable
        let logger: PrintLogger = Container.shared.logger()
        // This is also valid, but would crash:
        let invalidLogger: SomeStruct = Container.shared.logger()
    }
    
    struct SomeStruct { }
}
```

What I am trying to do is prevent `invalidLogger` from even compiling, because `SomeStruct` does not implement `T` - which is a `Loggable`

Is there any way to do this?

EDIT:

I'm looking for something similar to `func callAsFunction<U: T>() -> U` but that actually works.

Comment: Your code snippets are incomplete, full of unknowns and compilation errors. Try to post that fits together even if it 's not the complete code for the Factory type.

Comment: I gave more context and fixed the code blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing cannot work. In particular, this function is making a promise:

```
func callAsFunction<U>() -> U
```

It claim that the caller can pass **any** type U and this function will either return an instance of U or will never return. ("Never return" means an infinite loop or crashing. It's technically the same as returning a value of the type `Never`, which you can pretend in this case is a subtype of every type.)

The compiler gives no error for `any Invalid` because it's of type U, and you wrote a function that returns that.

In the case that you've given here, the answer is to remove the extension, and catch the error during construction. I've had to guess at what Factory looks like (and maybe the problem is that it is over-clever and filled with Any, which is a bad idea, but assuming it looks like this):

```
struct Factory<T> {
    var f: () -> T
    init(_:T, f: @escaping (() -> T)) { self.f = f }
    public func callAsFunction() -> T {
        f() // I assume ultimately this is what "registration.resolve(with: ())" does
    }
}
```

Then the basic stuff:

```
protocol P {}
struct MockP: P {}
protocol Invalid {}

class Container: P {
    static var shared = Container()
}
extension Container {
    var mockP: Factory<any P> {
         Factory<any P>(self) { MockP() }
    }
}
```

And using it:

```
let mock: any P = Container.shared.mockP() // Compiler time OK
let invalid: any Invalid = Container.shared.mockP() // Compile time ERROR
```

And if you make MockP not conform to P, then the compile error happens at the definition of `mockP`.

That said, I'm sure that Factory doesn't quite work like this and that there's more to the problem. You'll need to edit your question to include what else there is. But your extension does nothing useful (it can only work when it isn't needed). So I would go back to what your real problem is.

---

Given your updated code, this is impossible, for the same reasons. If you want to ensure that `Container.shared.logger()` is a PrintLogger, that's straight-forward: construct a `Factory<PrintLogger>`, not a `Factory<any Loggable>`. You've explicitly said that Factory does not know what underlying type it returns at runtime and that this may be determined at runtime and change. You cannot then ask the compiler to enforce something specific in that case. To make the compiler enforce it, set the type to what you want (`Factory<PrintLogger>`).

Comment: The function is not useless, it tries to cast a given object (an instance that conforms to a certain protocol for example) to a given type, which typically for us is the protocol, so we treat with the protocol instead of the instance. If there cast is not possible it returns never or crashes, that's why we want to check it on compile time. Bear in mind that Factory is a external library and we're just able to extend it. Edit: Container should not conform to any external protocol like P, is just a container of computed properties of different factory registration instances.

Comment: "Casting" is a runtime operation. You cannot do this at compile-time. At compile-time you must prove what the types are, and they must be known at compile-time. If they are known at compile time, then your function doesn't do anything. Either you request a type compatible with T (in which case the code you've shown should work without an extension), or it is not compatible with T, in which case it is known to fail. There is no meaning of U in this. You will need to show a complete example that compiles or fails to compile that shows the actual problem. As asked, the answer is it's impossible.

Comment: A possible confusion is that you're doing things like `Factory<any P>`. It's important to know that `any P` does not itself conform to P, and so cannot be passed to function that require that. That may be a piece of your problem. (In some cases this is relaxed a bit more in Swift 5.9, and some things that didn't work in the past may be ok there due to implictly opened existentials, but how they work can be subtle.) As a rule, it is challenging to work with `any` types in generic contexts, and it should be avoided if possible.

Comment: I want to guarantee at compile time that if I request a registered protocol that has an associated protocol in the registration (T) or to summarize, that a generic U inside T is conformed (U: T) but that's not possible because T is not known to be a protocol always, it can be an struct or a class. I can try to add more information to the question but that's all the code I have for now to offer.

Comment: I know that Factory<any P> does not make Factory implement P by any means, but it concretizes the generic that is shown in the code example. Container is just a bunch of factories of type T being registered that are retrieved using the callAsfunction() method (because they're properties of Container)

Comment: I don't mean that Factory would conform to P. I mean that in `Factory<any P>`, T does not conform to P. `any P` does not conform to P. When you say things like "assocated protocol in the in registration," it sounds like you're treating a protocol as a type when that is not true, and I suspect is influencing more of your underlying issue, which is not being shown here. If what you're showing here is 100% of your entire issue, the answer is "that's impossible," so I'm hoping there is actually more to your issue so it's solvable. Code like this is usually just a misdesign.

Comment: If the point of Factory is to throw a bunch of things of various types into a bucket and then get them back out in a type-safe way, then you want to look at how SwiftUI's Environment works or the new Foundation AttributeContainer. They demonstrate how to go about this kind of problem. It is never with `as` casting.

Comment: I've updated the code snippets in the question Rob. I hope that helps out.

Answer (score 0):

In **Swift**, it is not possible to achieve compile-time checking for the kind of restriction you're looking for using extensions. The extension you provided operates at runtime and relies on type casting, which can only be checked at runtime.

To enforce the constraint that the generic type `T` must conform to `P` when using the `callAsFunction` method you can try this (creating func instead of extent):

```
protocol P {}

struct Valid: P {}
struct Invalid {}

struct Factory<T> {
    func callAsFunction<U: P>() -> U {
        guard let result = callAsFunction() as? U else {
            fatalError("Found '\(T.self)', but unable to convert it to '\(U.self)'")
        }
        return result
    }
    
    func callAsFunction<U>() -> U {
        fatalError("Found '\(T.self)', but unable to convert it to '\(U.self)'")
    }
}

let result: Valid = Factory<P>().callAsFunction() // Compiler error: Invalid conversion
let invalid: Invalid = Factory<P>().callAsFunction() // Compiler error: Invalid does not conform to P
```

I created two separate `callAsFunction` **methods**:

- **The first** one is only available when the generic type `U` conforms to the protocol `P`, ensuring that the constraint is satisfied at compile-time.
- **The second** `callAsFunction` method is a fallback that will be used when the type `U` **does not conform** to `P`

If you want to retsrict the generic type `U` to be the same as `T`, you can **modify the code** like that:

```
protocol P {}

struct Valid: P {}
struct Invalid {}

struct Factory<T> {
    func callAsFunction<U>() -> U where U == T {
        guard let result = callAsFunction() as? U else {
            fatalError("Found '\(T.self)', but unable to convert it to '\(U.self)'")
        }
        return result
    }
    
    func callAsFunction<U>() -> U {
        fatalError("Found '\(T.self)', but unable to convert it to '\(U.self)'")
    }
}

let result: Valid = Factory<P>().callAsFunction() // Compiler error: Invalid conversion
let invalid: Invalid = Factory<P>().callAsFunction() // Compiler error: Invalid conversion
```

- **With this modification**, you can achieve **compile-time checking** to ensure that the generic type `U` **matches** the type `T` when calling the `callAsFunction` method.

I hope it helps.. If so, please **leave your opinions**!! ^^

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that's not though, I don't want to restrict to `P` but to restrict to `T`, `func callAsFunction<U: T>() -> U` but that's not valid in Swift.

Comment: The proposed solution is not valid either because `U == T` enforces same type, which implies that U and T are the same, so the restriction has no effect and will fail with checking that `Valid` conforms to `P` and the second one does not conform to it. Take in mind that `T` can be either a type or a protocol. Also the restriction `U: T` makes a compiler error. So there's no solution?